# iOS Swift - Use predicate core data to filter a tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, filter, predicate

I'm trying to filter my `NSFetchedResultsController` object when I search in the tableView. I have tried with `NSPredicate` but I can't make it work.
**I'm using Swift 3.**
This is my code:

```
func filtrarContenido(searchText: String) {
    let buscar = searchText.lowercased()

    let nombrePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nombre_comercial contains[cd] %@", buscar)
    let razSocialPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "razon_social contains[cd] %@", buscar)
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [nombrePredicate, razSocialPredicate])

    let respuesta = self.funcCoreData.obtenerResultadosFiltrados(entidad: "Clientes", orden: "nombre_comercial", ascendente: true, predicate: predicate)
    self.resultadosFiltrados = respuesta[1] as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>

    do {
        try self.resultadosFiltrados.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print(" \(error)")
    }
}
```

And here is the function in FuncCoreData file, it returns an array with the `NSManagedObject` and `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
func obtenerResultadosFiltrados(entidad: String, orden: String, ascendente: Bool, predicate: NSPredicate) -> [AnyObject] {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let objeto = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entidad)
    let ordenacion = NSSortDescriptor(key: orden, ascending: ascendente)
    objeto.sortDescriptors = [ordenacion]
    objeto.predicate = predicate

    print("OBJETO: ", objeto)

    let recorrerResultados = NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>(fetchRequest: objeto, managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: "seccionLetra", cacheName: nil)

    var array = [AnyObject]()
    array.append(objeto)
    array.append(recorrerResultados)

    return array
}
```

Well, is no getting any error, but the searching is always return empty, I think my expression in predicate is not correct:
`NSPredicate(format: "razon_social contains[cd] %@", buscar)`

Moreover, I want to make it **insensitive**, that is achieved with `ANY razon_social ..` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with a little help some days ago, and I'm going to share it with you.

```
var estaBuscando = false
let funcCoreData = FuncCoreData()
var resultados: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchedResultsController()
var resultadosFiltrados: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchedResultsController()
var objeto: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchRequest()
var aFiltrados = [Cliente]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let respuesta = self.funcCoreData.obtenerResultados(entidad: "Clientes", orden: "nombre_comercial", ascendente: true)
    self.objeto = respuesta[0] as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>
    self.resultados = respuesta[1] as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>
    do {
        try self.resultados.performFetch()
        self.pintarSecciones()
    } catch {
        print(" \(error)")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if estaBuscando {
        let obj2 = self.aFiltrados[indexPath.item]
        cell.codigo.text = obj2.codigo
        cell.titulo.text = obj2.nombre
        cell.subtitulo.text = obj2.razonSocial
        return cell;
    } else {
        if let obj = self.resultados.object(at: indexPath) as? Clientes {
            cell.codigo.text = obj.codigo!
            cell.titulo.text = obj.nombre_comercial!
            cell.subtitulo.text = obj.razon_social!
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func filtrarContenido(searchText: String) {
    let buscar = searchText.lowercased()

    let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "nombre_comercial contains[cd] %@", buscar)
    let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "razon_social contains[cd] %@", buscar)
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [p1, p2])
    let respuesta = self.funcCoreData.obtenerResultadosFiltrados(entidad: "Clientes", orden: "nombre_comercial", ascendente: true, predicate: predicate)
    self.resultadosFiltrados = respuesta[1] as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>

    do {
        try self.resultadosFiltrados.performFetch()
        self.aFiltrados = [Cliente]() // limpiar listado
        // convertir cada resultado obtenido al modelo Cliente
        for cli in self.resultadosFiltrados.fetchedObjects as! [Clientes] {
            let cliente = Cliente()
            cliente.convertir(cliente: cli)
            self.aFiltrados.append(cliente)
        }
    } catch {
        print(" Filtrar clientes \(error)")
    }
}

func searchDisplayController(_ controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool {
    self.filtrarContenido(searchText: searchString!)
    return true
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if(searchText.isEmpty) {
        estaBuscando = false
    } else {
        estaBuscando = true
    }
    self.filtrarContenido(searchText: searchText)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

File: FuncCoreData.swift

```
func obtenerResultadosFiltrados(entidad: String, orden: String, ascendente: Bool, predicate: NSPredicate) -> [AnyObject] {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let objeto = recorrerObjeto(entidad: entidad, orden: orden, ascendente: ascendente)
    objeto.predicate = predicate
    let recorrerResultados = NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>(fetchRequest: objeto, managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: "seccionLetra", cacheName: nil)

    var array = [AnyObject]()
    array.append(objeto)
    array.append(recorrerResultados)

    return array
}

func obtenerResultados(entidad: String, orden: String, ascendente: Bool) -> [AnyObject] {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let objeto = recorrerObjeto(entidad: entidad, orden: orden, ascendente: ascendente)
    let recorrerResultados = NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>(fetchRequest: objeto, managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: "seccionLetra", cacheName: nil)

    var array = [AnyObject]()
    array.append(objeto)
    array.append(recorrerResultados)

    return array
}

func recorrerObjeto(entidad: String, orden: String, ascendente: Bool) -> NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> {
    let objeto = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entidad)
    let ordenacion = NSSortDescriptor(key: orden, ascending: ascendente, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
    objeto.sortDescriptors = [ordenacion]
    return objeto
}
```

File: Clientes+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
extension Clientes {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Clientes> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Clientes>(entityName: "Clientes");
    }

    @NSManaged public var cif_dni: String?
    @NSManaged public var codigo: String?
    @NSManaged public var domicilio: String?
    ...

    var seccionLetra: String? {
        let letra = nombre_comercial!.characters.map { String($0) }
        return letra[0].uppercased()
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT!!** File: Cliente.swift.
An object class 'Cliente' with function 'convertir()'.
This class works like an object with which 'aFiltrados'is filled, and to filter a CoreData object is required to transform it to this object 'Cliente'.

```
import UIKit

class Cliente {
    var codigo = ""
    var nombre = ""
    ...
    ...

    func convertir(cliente: Clientes) {
        codigo = cliente.cif_dni!
        nombre = cliente.nombre_comercial!
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate looks valid to me. "c" is for caseInsensitive and "d" for accents and stuff like that.

I've tried to set up a project similar to yours, with an entity called Clientes, containing 3 optional Strings called nombre_comercial, razon_social and seccionLetra, used your functions and it seems to be working.

I have tried printing the results right after your performFetch() and got correct results.

```
do {
    try resultadosFiltrados.performFetch()
    if let results = resultadosFiltrados.fetchedObjects as? [Clientes] {
        print ("results.count \(results.count)")
        for cliente in results {
            print("nombre comercial \(cliente.nombre_comercial! )")
        }
     }            
} catch {
    print(" \(error)")
}
```

You should try to check if your data is correct, by removing the predicate for example, to see the complete results, and so on.